# Authenticate in PHP with OS username/password?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm wondering if there's a way to use PHP (or perhaps some other CGI, but preferably PHP) to authenticate a user with their OS (in this case, Linux, Debian 5) username and password. Possible? Difficult? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly this question belongs, but it certainly touches on Serverfault's remit, so it might be worth exploring over there as well.

Comment: @ricebowl - I'd say it's worth posting on both. Leveraging an OS-level auth mechanism is definitely in the realms of programming. On the other hand, the mechanisms offered by a particular OS would be in the realms of server admin.

Answer (score 4):

Generally this kind of stuff is OS-specific and hooks into existing authentication procedures.  For Linux, you might want to check out PAM...  There is a [PECL module for PAM](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) which could help you accomplish this.  I imagine you have to configure PAM to allow this type of authentication, so it could require some system administrative work.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean with their login credentials on the Server it depends on how the authentication is handled, (mostly with one of the PAM backends)

then the easiest way would be to use http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to execute some sort of login using the php exec() command.

I am not a sysadmin so I don't know what the command would be, but if you can find a login command, you can use PHP to pass that command and then parse the results.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a 10 year old question, it came up when I was searching with the same problem today.

In case it helps anyone, here's how I solved it for my use case (Debian on a Raspberry Pi):

```
function checkLogin($user, $password) {
    return exec("echo $password | su $login -c 'echo Yes'") == 'Yes';
}
```

It could no doubt be improved (santity-checking the $user/$password values for example) but I'm sharing because it might help someone out.